# Is it possible to pull the build number from a running Google Container-Optimized OS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-os

According to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/resources/sources), one can pull the kernel sources from the following location in Google Cloud Storage.

```
gs://cos-tools/<build-number>/
```

I am trying to find the source for a running instance of the Container-Optimized OS, but I have not found documentation describing how to extract a build number from the running instance. The output of `uname -r` is `4.4.111+` but I do not know how to map this to a build number that I can use for pulling the source.

How does one find the build number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the running COS instance, you can find the version in `/etc/lsb-release`.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release | grep CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION=10452.101.0
```

Then, in a machine with `gsutil` installed and configured

```
$ gsutil ls gs://cos-tools/10452.101.0/
gs://cos-tools/10452.101.0/kernel-src.tar.gz
gs://cos-tools/10452.101.0/kernel-src.tar.gz.md5
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to look at `/etc/os-release`:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release | grep BUILD_ID
BUILD_ID=12607.7.0
```

See [this Chromium OS design doc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/os_config.md#os-release) for more details of the meaning of all the fields in `/etc/lsb-release` and `/etc/os-release` in Chromium OS, and whether you can rely on it or not. Container-optimized OS is [based on](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/) Chromium OS.